# Flip value randomly based on count of values in particular column in another table

Tags: c#

For one row in table fruits, two rows are created in table market with the same values in all columns except the status column. If fid = mid, fnumber = mnumber and fquantity = mquantity, and if for that matching rows fstatus = yellow then I want to flip its mstatus to 'SOLD'.

I'm unable to understand what logic can be used. I've to use the language C#. the code I've written does not obviously work. Can someone tell me what should be done?

Part of code/pseudo code:

```
foreach (DataRow f in fruitsDS.Tables["fruits"].Rows)
{
    foreach (DataRow m in marketDS.Tables["market"].Rows)
    {
        if (m.mid == f["fid"].ToString() && m.mnumber == f["fnumber"].ToString() && 
            Math.Abs(m.mquantity).Equals(f["fquantity"]))
        {
            if (f["fstatus"].ToString() == "black" && m.mstatus == "packed")
            {
                m.quantitystatus = "FORECAST";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Actual Tables:

```
Market          
market  mid  mnumber  mquantity  mstatus
p       1    102      100        packed
p       1    101      100        packed
p       1    101      100        packed
p       1    103      200        packed
m       1    102      100        packed
m       1    101      100        packed
m       1    101      100        packed
m       1    103      200        packed

Fruits  
fid  fnumber  fquantity  fstatus
1    101      100        black
1    102      100        yellow
1    101      100        black
1    103      200        yellow
```

Expected Result:

```
Market          
market  mid  mnumber  mquantity  mstatus
p       1    102      100        sold
p       1    101      100        packed
p       1    101      100        packed
p       1    103      200        sold
m       1    102      100        sold
m       1    101      100        packed
m       1    101      100        packed
m       1    103      200        sold

Fruits  
fid  fnumber  fquantity  fstatus
1    101      100        black
1    102      100        yellow
1    101      100        black
1    103      200        yellow
```

For example: in fruits there is same fid, fnumber and fquantity for two rows, i.e. 1, 101 and 100 but different fstatus 'black' and 'yellow'. Two rows are created for each record in the market table but with same status purchase so there's no way of differentiating as all other values are same. If there is one 'yellow' I want to flip two rows in market table, one with market value 'p' and one with market value 'm' for fid = mid, fnumber = mnumber and fquantity = mquantity. How to do that in C#?

Comment: what's the difference between quantitystatus and mquantity ?  I don't see a corresponding column in your table for quantitystatus

Comment: In your posted table you have two rows 1, 101, 100 with same fstatus black - why do you say it is different?